# How to log executing details in the console with Robot Framework data-driven mode?

Tags: python, robotframework

According to the sample given by the Robot Framework data-driven mode, while executing it only output the high-level test case info and without the arguments.

How can I set the test to have the not only the high-level case name, but also the keywords inside the test case and the which arguments is running now?

```
*** Settings ***
Test Template    Login with invalid credentials should fail

*** Test Cases ***                USERNAME         PASSWORD
Invalid User Name                 invalid          ${VALID PASSWORD}
Invalid Password                  ${VALID USER}    invalid
Invalid User Name and Password    invalid          invalid
Empty User Name                   ${EMPTY}         ${VALID PASSWORD}
Empty Password                    ${VALID USER}    ${EMPTY}
Empty User Name and Password      ${EMPTY}         ${EMPTY}
```

Comment: I don't understand your question. When I run the code in your question and I have multiple statements in `Login with invalid credentials should fail`, I see all of the statements in the log for each test case. Are you asking about how to see the parameters in the console output?

Comment: Yes, I'm asking about how to see the parameters in the console output. Since it's data-driven mode, data should be a important part of the test, I would like to know which params is running and the status. Thank you.